# Django authenticate not keeping user logged in

Tags: python, django, web, authentication

I am attempting to learn Django's authentication system by contriving a basic login scenario. My views are set up such that a view, `logIn`, either receives a user's credentials (and prints the success/failure of the login), or it renders a login form.

A second view, `privatePage`, is designed as a sanity check that the user is actually logged in. The code is as follows:

### `views.py`:

```
@login_required(login_url='/logIn')
def privatePage(request):
    return HttpResponse("You're viewing a private page")

@csrf_exempt
def logIn(request):
    if request.method == "POST" and \
       request.POST.get('email') and \
       request.POST.get('password'):
        user = authenticate(username=request.POST['email'], 
                            password=request.POST['password'])
        return HttpResponse('Valid login' if user is not None else 'Invalid login')
    # render login form
    return HttpResponse("<form>...</form>")
```

I'm finding that after succcessfully logging in via the `logIn` view, I am still redirected to the login view upon trying to visit `privatePage`. FYI, I'm attempting to visit the `privatePage` view directly by URL, as opposed to navigating through provided links (e.g. I'm not sure if I'm violating some CSRF rule).

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've not actually logged in. You need to *login* the user after verifying their identity with `authenticate`:

```
from django.contrib.auth import login

user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
```

`login` should only be used on users that have been confirmed to exist.

---

What `authenticate` does:

> verifies a user is who they claim to be

It does not perform the actual *login*.

Comment: authenticate takes `username` and `password` right ?

Comment: @RajaSimon Not necessarily. Username and password are default. However, email can also be used.

Comment: I tried with `email` & `password`, It doesn't return user object

Comment: If you set the `USERNAME_FIELD` in your User model to `email`, then `email` can be used with `authenticate`

Answer (score 0):

To keep the user logged in a `session` must be provided to user with usage of `login()` method. Login is the process of providing user with a session and `authenticate() verifies that the given credentials corresponds to an existing user model object in database` . Import django's built in login and authenticate methods `from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login`. And then your code looks like

```
user =authenticate(email, password)
    If user:
        login(user, request)
```

Hope it helps :)